# Loading of .bashrc fails when I open "first" terminal. But is loaded when I open tmux and/or I try to create new window with Ctrl+SHIFT+N

Tags: ubuntu, bash, dotfiles

I've created my own dotfile repository and this is the install.sh file, that load all stuffs:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Installation started"

SCRIPT=$(readlink -f $0)
SCRIPTPATH=`dirname $SCRIPT`

cd $SCRIPTPATH && git submodule update -i

echo "Install some useful program"
sudo apt-get install tmux
sudo apt-get install xclip

echo "Replace old ~/.git-prompt.sh"
rm ~/.git-prompt.sh
ln -s $SCRIPTPATH/.git-prompt.sh ~/.git-prompt.sh

echo "Replace old ~/.tmux.conf"
rm ~/.tmux.conf
ln -s $SCRIPTPATH/.tmux.conf ~/.tmux.conf

echo "Replace old ~/.gitconfig"
rm ~/.gitconfig
ln -s $SCRIPTPATH/.gitconfig ~/.gitconfig

echo "Replace old ~/.bashrc file"
rm ~/.bashrc
ln -s $SCRIPTPATH/.bashrc ~/.bashrc

echo "Replace old ~/.profile file"
rm ~/.profile
ln -s $SCRIPTPATH/.profile ~/.profile

echo "Replace old ~/.vim folder"
rm -rf ~/.vim
ln -s $SCRIPTPATH/.vim ~/.vim

echo "Replace old ~/.vimrc file"
rm ~/.vimrc
ln -s $SCRIPTPATH/.vimrc ~/.vimrc

echo "done!"
```

Finally, this is a part of my .bashrc file:

```
# Prompt colors
Red="\[\e[0;31m\]"
Darkgreen="\[\e[0;32m\]"
Green="\[\e[1;32m\]"
White="\[\e[0;0m\]"
Yellow="\[\e[1;33m\]"

# Show git branch name
source ~/.git-prompt.sh

# Custom prompt
export PS1="${Red}\u ${Yellow}\A ${Darkgreen}\w${Green}$(__git_ps1) \$ ${White}"

# Wondering in folders
alias ..="cd .."
alias ...=".. && .."
alias ....=".. && .. && .."

# Listing 
alias ll="ls -l"
alias la="ls -la"

# Fix git configurations
git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim

# Colors
alias grep="grep --color"
alias ls="ls --color"
```

I am on Ubuntu. When I click on Terminal's icon, the Terminal were opened. But `.bashrc` is never loaded in this moment. `.bashrc` is loaded if:

- I run "source ~/.bashrc" manually
- I open new terminal with CTRL+SHIFT+N
- I run tmux

Why ubuntu do not load .bashrc at the first time?
Some additional informations could be:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: your `bashrc` loaded only then you open new shell from existed shell(or run subshell), but `bash_profile` loaded only once when terminal open. Add to bottom of your `bash_profile` this `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc`. That loaded your `bashrc` when `bash_profile` loaded.

Comment: I've added .bash_profile with the content "source ~/.bashrc" but is not working ... =(

Comment: things what i explain it is like `bash` work, i sure that you doing something wrong.

Comment: i just know that the shell running under tmux is not a login shell.

Comment: Terminal I open is the one I can open with a click from ubuntu interface.